# Registering a function to be called on an event in Python

Tags: python, events, callback, function-pointers

I want to write a function that will be called after an event occurred but only if the user has registered it.

e.g.

```
#Defination
def fnBookUber(objUser):
    print 'Inside fbBookUber()'

#calling
def myEvent(objUser):
    print 'This event has fired'
    # This function will fill objUser too
    fnBookUber(objUser)

#Registeration
fnRegisterRideBooking(fnBookUber)
```

I know my explanation is little wonky but I don't have any idea how this would be done in python, though I strongly there must be many ways of doing this in python. 
Also, I assume this is achievable using **function pointers** in C++ and **delegates** in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can register and call events.

```
import types

#Callback
def fnBookUber(objUser):
    print('Inside fbBookUber()')

class myEvent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = list()

    def registerCallback(self, callback: types.FunctionType):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)

    def call(self, objUser):
        print('This event has fired')

        for callback in self.callbacks:
            callback(objUser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myEvent = myEvent()

    #Registration
    myEvent.registerCallback(fnBookUber)

    #Calling/Firing the event
    myEvent.call()
```

You can also pass the function directly, such as

```
def myEvent(objUser, callback):
    print('This event has fired')
    callback(objUser)
```

And call the event as:

```
myEvent(objUser, fnBookUber)
```

This is less flexible than the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Though I've accepted the above answer because of its completeness here is another way that I've used to implement this mechanism in my code.

```
#callbackIDs
cbUberId = 1
cbCareemId = 2
cbBykea = 3
cbDic = {}

#definations
def RegisterCallbacks(cbId, functionPointer):
    global cbDic
    cbdic[cbId] = cbFunc
    print 'Updated callback dictionary with cbId = %s and function Name = %s' % 
    (cbID,functionPointer.__name__) 

def myEvent(objUser, desiredRideID):
    print 'Inside myEvent'
    if (cbDic[desiredRideID]):
        cbDic[desiredRideID](objUser)
def GUIFunction(objUser):
     print 'GUI fucntion'
     ...[do whatever you want with objUser]

#calling 
RegisterCallbacks(cbCareemId, GUIFunction)   
myEvent(object, cbCareemId)
```

This is a rough idea that how I have implemented the overall logic. I was able to manage multiple callbacks in an easy way.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the `Decorators` to complete you code.

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        print('call %s():' % func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper

@log
def now():
    print('2015-3-25')

>>> now()
call now():
2015-3-25
```

you also visit the link:https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/ for more help.

Comment: Leider! This does not make any sense to me. Where is the registration and event raising part?